# clutch,transfercase,manual,gears? Help 1994 toyota 4 runner

Tags: toyota, clutch, manual-transmission, gear-stick, 4runner

My 1994 4 runner will go into gear, but will not move. It does not jerk or stop running when i let clutch out while in gear? Is it the clutch, trance-fer case or something else? And if it is trance fer case can i unhook 4 wheel drive, can i drive it in 2 wheel drive?

Comment: Please do not create ask a new question the same as your previous question. Please create a full up account and we can get your questions attached to it. Also, I already answered your question. I really don't know why you asked it again.